# How to update automatically a file when committing with SVN

Tags: svn

#### Probably duplicate of

- [Subversion as version-incrementor at each commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438398/subversion-as-version-incrementor-at-each-commit)
- [post commit hook to update a file under version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650168/post-commit-hook-to-update-a-file-under-version)
- ...

I'm looking for a way to update a file (let's say lastbuild.txt) with the last SVN revision number when I commit.
How can I do that ?

thank you :)

Comment: you cant modify files under version control with a post commit hook.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650168/post-commit-hook-to-update-a-file-under-version
The only option is to do it with a build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN supports hooks - scripts or programs that get called on certain actions. You may set a post-commit hook that will update file for you.

Read more on hooks [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/244.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

If the file is under versioning you can use svn:keywords it's way easier than hooks.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following documentation:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks